# Combining desired features of multiple images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have found multiple tutorials for OCR but it’s the next step that I am unsure about and would like to be pointed in the right direction. Ideally, I would be able to choose from a list of desired features and it could produce an image combining them. Currently I’m only working with basic diagrams (Courtesy of MS paint) but intend for there to be more parameters and for the input images to be more complex.

For example, my input images would show only one feature

A.[Feature A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv3JU.png)

B.[Feature B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce4Xx.png)

C.[Feature C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbBT7.png)

D.[Feature D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjUsc.png)

And if I asked for a combination of A and D it could produce

Out:[Features A & D Combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbsG.png)

Have I completely lost it?

p.s. Sorry the images are so small I thought was being efficient.

Comment: If the features are always dark compared to the white foreground, you can take the element-wise min for block and the features.  If not, you can set each block equal the feature you want (e.g., feature A in quadrant 1, feature D in in quadrant 4, etc.) and iterate over the blocks--maybe I"m missing something?

Comment: I think this might be off topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic]. You can find a discussion of Machine Learning related Stack Exchange sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524).